# Java: IndexOf(String string) that returns wrong character

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, indexof

I am writing a file browser program that displays file directory path while a user navigates between folders/files.

I have the following String as file path:

```
"Files > Cold Storage > C > Capital"
```

I am using Java `indexOf(String)` method to return the index of `'C'` character between `> C >`, but it returns the first occurrence for it from this word `Cold`.

I need to get the `'C'` alone which sets between `> C >`.
This is my code:

```
StringBuilder mDirectoryPath = new StringBuilder("Files > Cold Storage > C > Capital");
String mTreeLevel = "C";
int i = mDirectoryPath.indexOf(mTreeLevel);
if (i != -1) {
    mDirectoryPath.delete(i, i + mTreeLevel.length());
}
```

I need flexible solution that fits other proper problems 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: simply check if the word has a space before and after the character

Comment: Could you just use `indexOf("> " + mTreeLevel + " >") + 2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach would be to use a `List` of `String`s.

```
public void test() {
    List<String> directoryPath = Arrays.asList("Files", "Cold Storage", "C", "Capital");
    int cDepth = directoryPath.indexOf("C");
    System.out.println("cDepth = " + cDepth);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Search for the first occurance of " C " :

```
String mTreeLevel = " C ";
int i = mDirectoryPath.indexOf(mTreeLevel);
```

Then add 1 to account to get the index of `'C'` (assuming the String you searched for was found).

If you only want to delete the single 'C' character :

```
if (i >= 0) {
    mDirectoryPath.delete(i + 1, i + 2);
}
```

EDIT:

If searching for `" C "` may still return the wrong occurrence, search for `" > C > "` instead.

Comment: Assume I have this string `"Files > Cold C Storage > C > Capital"` then it will get the wrong occurrence for ` C ` !!

Comment: @blueware You can search for  "> C >" instead.